# How to query a pandas column with tuples

Tags: python, pandas

How to query a column holding tuples?

```python
     # Tuples in a dataframe
     _df = pd.DataFrame({'C': [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5)]})
     display(_df)

     for i in range(len(_df)):
         _df.loc[i, 'D'] = sum(_df.loc[i, 'C'])
     display(_df)


          C
    0   (0, 1)
    1   (2, 3)
    2   (4, 5)
```

How to query for for example all tuples in C having a tuple of which the first element == 2 ?

```
    _df[_df['C'] == (2, 3)]
```

matches on the tuple. But how to match just an element of a tuple ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `str[0]` for select first values of tuples:

```
print (_df['C'].str[0])
0    0
1    2
2    4
Name: C, dtype: int64

print (_df[_df['C'].str[0] == 2])
        C
1  (2, 3)
```

Comment: Yep, that did it!

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
_df[pd.Series(zip(*_df['C'])[0])==2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
>>> _df.loc[_df['C'].apply(pd.Series)[0]==2]
        C
1  (2, 3)
```

`pd.Series` 'splits' each tuple. `[0]` gets the first item that results from the tuple. `df.loc` finds the row matching the condition.